# Reset status bar color

Tags: flutter

I made status bar same color as app bar:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: myAppBarColor,
));
```

But when I show a modal bottom sheet, status bar is displayed over the dark overlay:

[image]

I want to to shade status bar together with app bar. How do I reset status bar color back to default?

I tried passing `statusBarColor: null` (before showing modal bottom sheet) but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make status bar color transparent (in main function):

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
));
```